# Hibernate Criteria with composite-id - could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, criteria, composite-id

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.2.Final and in the mapping.xml, I have a composite id like this:

```
<class name="OrganisationSpecialist" table="organisation_specialist">
    <composite-id mapped="false" unsaved-value="undefined">
        <key-many-to-one class="Organisation" column="ORGANISATION_ID" lazy="false" name="organisation" />
        <key-many-to-one class="Specialist" column="SPECIALIST_ID" lazy="false" name="specialist" />
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

The following code works

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(OrganisationSpecialist.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organisation.organisationId", organisationId));
```

When I add an statement with a property present in my model Organisation like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(OrganisationSpecialist.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organisation.organisationId", organisationId));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organisation.deleted", true));
```

I get the error message:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: organisation.deleted of: ch.xxx.yyy.model.OrganisationSpecialist
```

I also tried using alias for the property deleted like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(OrganisationSpecialist.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organisation.organisationId", organisationId));
    criteria.createAlias("organisation", "o").add(Restrictions.eq("o.deleted", false));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organisation.deleted", true));
```

When I'm using HQL Query, my query works.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from OrganisationSpecialist where organisation.organisationId=:orgId and organisation.deleted=false");
    query.setParameter("orgId", organisationId);
```

Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong? I thought that every query possible in HQL are also possible using Criteria.

Thanks for explanation